# Query returning users, first record and last record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to write a query showing our unique users, the date of their first recorded entry in the system and the date of their last recorded entry. These are split between two tables: Users table and log table.

Users:

```
| Userid | Username    |
|--------|-------------|
|20      | Tom Smith   |
|21      | Jim Jones   |
|22      | Sandy Brown |
```

Log:

```
| Logid | UserID  | Date       | Value        |
--------|---------|------------|--------------|
| 1     | 21      | 01/03/2013 | Login        |
| 2     | 22      | 01/04/2013 | Login        |
| 3     | 21      | 01/05/2013 | Edit         |
| 4     | 20      | 01/06/2013 | Login        |
| 5     | 20      | 01/07/2013 | Search       |
| 6     | 22      | 01/08/2013 | Login        |
| 7     | 21      | 01/09/2013 | Close        |
| 8     | 21      | 01/11/2013 | Login        |
| 9     | 20      | 01/12/2013 | Edit         |
| 10    | 22      | 01/13/2013 | Search       |
```

This is the desired result of the query I am attempting to write:

```
|Userid | UserName    | First Log Date | Last Log Date |
|-------|-------------|----------------|---------------|
| 20    | Tom Smith   | 01/06/2013     | 01/12/2013    |
| 21    | Jim Jones   | 01/03/2013     | 01/11/2013    |
| 22    | Sandy Brown | 01/04/2013     | 01/13/2013    |
```

So far I have the first two columns, however I cannot figure out the First and Last date columns, below is my query so far:

```
select 
    distinct(u.userid1) as 'Userid',
    u.username as 'UserName'
from 
    users u,
    log l
where
    u.userid = l.userid
```

I am using SQL Server 2008. I would love some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the `min` and `max` of the date for each record.

```
select 
    u.userid as [Userid],
    u.username as [UserName],
    min([Date]) as [First Log Date],
    max([Date]) as [Last Log Date]
from users u 
inner join log l on u.userid = l.userid
group by u.userid, u.username
```

Comment: There's no need for distinct with the group by, but it still works.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables:  Actually, that appears to have come from the query in the original example (you probably just didn't notice it).  Either way, it works, so nice job.

Comment: Do not recommend the use of sql antipatterns such as implicit joins.

Comment: @HLGEM - you're absolutely right, that was sloppy on my part to copy-and-paste the user's query with that still intact.  I've updated my answer, and will be more dilligent in the future.  That's pretty embarassing :|

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to apply an aggregate function to get the `min` and `max` dates and then `group by u.userid, u.username`:

```
select u.userid as 'Userid',
  u.username as 'UserName',
  min(l.date) FirstDate,
  max(l.date) lastDate
from users u
inner join log l
  on u.userid = l.userid
group by u.userid, u.username
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e712/4)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a `group by`:

```
select u.userid, u.username,
       MIN(date) as FirstLogDate, MAX(date) as MaxLogDate
from users u join
     log l
      on u.userid = l.userid
group by u.userid, u.username
```